# DNS domain pointing to LAN ip only works from one device

Tags: networking, dns, lan, http, ipad

I'm running a HTTP website on port 61337 on my laptop.

My laptop's ip address is 192.168.1.247.

The domain `mathsrise.tk` points to `192.168.1.247`, and I can (from my laptop) access the website at this url: `http://mathsrise.tk:61337`.

Every other device in the house can access at `http://192.168.1.247:61337`, but they can't access the website from `http://mathsrise.tk:61337`, instead it says "the server cannot be found", or some equivalent.

E.g. pinging from a windows 7 desktop:

```
> ping mathsrise.tk
Ping request could not find host mathsrise.tk. Please check the name and try again.
```

Why is only one device correctly resolving the DNS? Or finding this "host" (idk what host means)

Comment: How is the iPad connected to the internet?

Comment: Can other hosts on your LAN resolve the domain name? Does your DNS server have protections against DNS rebinding, and can they be disabled?

Comment: @DavidPostill wifi to the same router laptop is connected to (both wifi)

Comment: @grawity Just tried from a desktop, didn't work. Ping shows `could not find host mathsrise.tk`.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I've already edited my router's `/etc/hosts` to do this. Do you know why it wasn't working originally though?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart oh I got it. Was some DHCP problem, I just had to renew laptop's lease. I don't really understand tbh but it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand it but I fixed all the problems by renewing my laptop's DHCP lease.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  I think you accomplished in a simpler way what Tim was describing in his answer (his instructions would more reliably fix a broader range of issues than the one underlying your problem).  Anyway, if you accept one of the answers, that will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't understand Tim's answer and can't accept mine for 48 hours

Answer (score 4):

Early in Ethernet networking, most networks consisted of many devices doing many different tasks.

Your average network had a Router, a Switch, firewall/NAT, a DHCP server, a DNS server, & web server.

All separate boxes, powered on the network. As time progressed, so did home networking devices and as the home networking devices started to get more powerful, in terms of CPU horsepower and massive amounts more in memory, they started to become “Combo” devices.

Fast forward to today, and your average home router is technically speaking, a Router, Switch, Bridge, Firewall/NAT, WiFi AP, DNS-forwarder, & DHCP server all in one unit.
Which can make things a little confusing if you are not familiar with networking lingo.
Make note, that most off the shelf routers are not DNS servers, they are DNS forwarders. Which just means that they pass along any requests to the DNS server that was allocated by the ISP through the WAN links DHCP.

Some higher end consumer routers do actually have the option to run a DNS  application/service on the router. (Turning the router into a DNS server.) the purpose of this is so people on the network dont have to remember IP numbers they can access local resources by typing in a domain format. (myshare.mylocaldomain.net instead of something like \\172.16.36.233\share-media)

When you stated “I've already edited my router's /etc/hosts to do this”.

I made an educated guess that,

1. your DNS server is running on the router not a separate box.
2. you have some sort of Linux based router running a DNS  application/service.
3. You have setup the local/private DNS record properly
4. your client PC's are either holding the wrong or old DNS cache information   or need the adapters DNS set automatically. (a lot of people use google DNS 8.8.8.8 setting the adapter statically)

You can clear the DNS cache a number of ways, a restart, Flushing the cache manually, and I also believe the windows connection troubleshooter also clears it. Some OS's will clear it when you bring the adapter down then back up. Which I believe is what happened in your case.

When you are setting DNS up from the router it will act as a server for the private LAN, looking at the records that have been created. If it doesn't match a record in the local table, it then acts as a DNS forwarder to the 1st ISP DNS public server, relaying the query. Note: some routers automatically make local DNS records based off of the clients set host-name when the router gives out a DHCP address.

When setting up a Local DNS server (not on a router),
All the local clients must either have the local DNS statically set in the adapter, or have the DHCP serving device handing out the Correct DNS servers for resolution.

You would set the DNS list in the NIC like this,
1. (192.168.1.x)Local DNS ip address, where x is the actual host serving DNS. 
2. The router or gateway of the ISP connection. Its usually 192.168.1.1 for home networking gear.

Hosts will go down the list in order trying to resolve DNS queries. It will first look at the local DNS for any Matches, If there is no match it will then move on to the next DNS server.

When creating a local DNS server, and after setting up new DHCP parameters. You should always release the old client side DHCP leases, and release any information being held in the DNS cache.

To release the DNS cache in Windows;

1. Click Start. Enter cmd in the Start menu search text box.
2. Right-click Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator. Run the following command: ipconfig /flushdns.

To release the DNS cache in Linux;

1. "$ sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart" or
2. "# service nscd restart" or
3. "# service nscd reload"

If i have missed anything, please leave me a comment.
Sorry about the original, I tried to generalize it a little bit in hopes it would not just help you but maybe help someone else searching. I hope this helps explain it, and I haven't confused you further.

Best Regards,

Comment: I used freenom to set the a records for my domain

Comment: "I've already edited my router's /etc/hosts to do this". i think you are confusing your local resolution with FQDN resolution

Comment: I don't know what a local DNS server is. I assumed it was some private DNS looked at by the router before the public DNSes. You can ping `mathsrise.tk` from your side of the internet and it should resolve to `192.168.1.247`. Is that a local DNS server? To be honest I don't understand this answer. Too complex for me, don't know most of the terminology.

Comment: It's ok, we are all learning in one subject or another. I'm a terrible writer, so please excuse that if it doesn't make sense, I'll try to edit it and reword it. DNS = hostname to IP address mapping. When referring to local, it means your private side IP address space (the 192.168.1.x network as opposed to your public address)